# JSPDF table alignment in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I have a table as follows.
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xNYa.png)

I want to download PDF in the same way but am getting the following way.

[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxRrU.png)

The following is my code in component.ts

```
exportReportPdf() {        
    var doc =  new jsPDF('p','pt','a4');
    var columns = [
        {title: "Serial Number", dataKey: "Serial_Number"},
        {title: "Type", dataKey: "Type"}, 
        {title: "Make", dataKey: "Make"},
        {title: "Model", dataKey: "Model"},
        {title: "Class", dataKey: "Class"},
        {title: "Capacity", dataKey: "Capacity"},
        {title: "Weight", dataKey: "Weight"},
        {title: "Lip Width", dataKey: "Lip_width"},
        {title: "Check-Out Date", dataKey: "CheckOut_Date"},
        {title: "Expected Return Date", dataKey: "Expected_CheckIn"},
        {title: "Customer Number", dataKey: "Customer_Number"},
        {title: "Customer Information", dataKey: "Customer_Information"},          
    ];

    doc.text(140, 40, "Report");
    doc.autoTable(columns, this.data,{
       margin: {top: 60},
       tableWidth: 'auto',
       styles: {overflow: 'linebreak',valign: 'middle',fontSize:9,cellPadding :3},

    });

    doc.save('reports.pdf');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jspdf-autotable does not support vertical headers. But you can style that yourself. You can modify the input data so that your headers are in a column and then style it using columnStyles.